# Cypher and Gremlin querying

Tags: graph, cypher, gremlin

I'm doing a research about graph query languages and I considered that Gremlin is dedicated for traversal querying and Cypher is efficient and more easy, but I can't find a concrete example that differentiate them.

Can some one give me some example of queries that we can do with Cypher and not with Gremlin or the opposite.

Thanks

Comment: related read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13824962/neo4j-cypher-vs-gremlin-query-language

Answer (score 0):

It's not a matter of what one language can do that the other language can't.  They're both complete enough that you can do any kind of graph query in either.  The question is simply how hard you'll have to work to make it happen, and whether the result will be performant, readable, and easy to change.

Cypher is a declarative language, meaning that you declare what you want to see, and the engine figures out how to get that data for you.  Gremlin is largely imperative, meaning that you specify how to traverse the graph.  This tends to make Gremlin more brittle,

Comment: Thanks for answering for my question, what you said is very important and it correspond with what i read along my research but really i want an example of query that differentiate the two languages.